# Seeing the code for a defunct iPhone app

Tags: ios

I have an app that I loved to use, it stopped working years ago and I kept it on my phone incase someday I ever decided to learn to program. I am very very new to programming and I would appreciate some direction from people more experienced.

Should I try to find a way to see the code used to make the app or should I just look at the features of the app and learn to make one that does the same things?

Comment: Decompiling the app will probably yield obfuscated code (not entirely sure, never done iOS dev), and may even violate Apple's/the app's TOS.

Comment: Unless the app is open-sourced you'll have a hard time looking at the source code. You can of course use a disassembler and look at the result, but it's likely you won't find it very usable.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't see the source code from an app unless the author decides to share it. The best you could do would be the machine code, and you'd need to be able to read ARM assembler in order for that to mean anything to you.

There are decompiler tools that will take machine code and use it to reverse-compile to source code, but their output ends up being pretty much unreadable. Plus it's a violation of Apple's terms of service.

Comment: For iOS decompiling resources see this post: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/possibilities-for-reverse-engineering-an-ipa-file-to-its-source

Answer (score 0):

Unless the developer has made (or is willing to make) the source code available somewhere, using the features as a specification is your only practical choice.

Reverse engineering a compiled application into usable source is non-trivial (!!!!).

Answer (score 0):

> should I just look at the features of the app and learn to make one that does the same things?

Yes, do that. It's a very good way to learn, and you'll end up with something you like.